# Send an Input/pass text file example.txt to Install.sh in Linux

Tags: linux, command-line

I have an install.sh file which needs an input from a text file example.txt

Is there a linux command which I can use like below:?

```
/Desktop/examples.txt | /bin/bash /a/b/install.sh
```

Comment: I am afraid this is an X - Y question... Do you mean send the `sudo` password?

Comment: `cat /Desktop/examples.txt | /bin/bash /a/b/install.sh` will do what you ask. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/bin/bash /a/b/install.sh < /Desktop/examples.txt